# Does there exist a power series such that points on its circle of convergence alternate infinitely often between convergence and divergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Does there exist a power series
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_nx^n}$$
with a radius of convergence of one such that points on its boundary circle in the complex plane alternate infinitely often between convergence and divergence?

I.e. for any $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $S$ converges at $e^{\theta_1i}$ and $e^{\theta_2i}$, there exists $\theta_1<\alpha\in \mathbb{R}<\theta_2$ such that $S$ diverges at $e^{\alpha i}$, and vice versa.

Comment: I like this question.  May be rephrased to ask about convergence of Fourier series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{i n \theta}$ .